# Display yaxis on left in d3

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to ensure that the y axis is always drawn on the left in d3.js? If there are no negative values then this will happen by default. I am looking for a way to place the y axis on the left even it there are negative values. This may seem odd but is required for the type of graph I need to create.

I am trying to adapt this Marginal Abatement Cost Curve (MACC) d3 example to display the y axis on the left despite having negative values. I have tried to use axis.orient and set this to left. The MACC code is open source and available here https://github.com/tamc/macc

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[D3 axis](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#orient) can be configured using its properties. Please have a look on the link so you will get a better idea for implementation

- d3 axis associated with d3.scale
- scale domain values to be visually encoded in pixels by range.
- Length of the axis will always with in the range.

To achieve negative values regardless of the domain, make a default negative minimum value in scale domain. By providing this you can have the axis alway starts with the negative value.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 400-margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200-margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([-10, 10])
    .range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```